# Changing "type" in hierarchy

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

**TL/DR** - Is there a way to force EF Core to allow me to update a Discriminator column?

I'm playing around with Entity Framework Core for the first time and trying to implement a simple system where I have Clients of 3 types to manage. Two of these types are only meaningfully different in their type value itself (`type1` and `type2`). The third type (`special`) just has an extended set of possible relationships.

So, in the database I created a single table to store the core data:

```
CREATE TABLE [Clients].[Clients](
    [ClientId] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ClientName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ProtocolType] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ClientLogoUrl] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Clients_Clients] PRIMARY KEY ([ClientId]),
 CONSTRAINT [UQ_Clients_Client_Names] UNIQUE ([ClientName]),
 CONSTRAINT [UQ_Clients_Client_Protocol_XRef] UNIQUE ([ClientId],[ProtocolType]),
 CONSTRAINT [FK_Clients_Client_Protocol] FOREIGN KEY([ProtocolType])
     REFERENCES [Clients].[Protocols] ([ProtocolType])
)
```

In my code I then created these models:

```
  public class Client
  {
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string ProtocolType { get; set; }
    public string ClientLogoUrl { get; set; }
    public Protocol Protocol { get; set; }
  }
```

And for the one subtype of Clients that have more possible relationships:

```
  public class SpecialClient : Client
  {
    public List<Service> Services { get; set; }
    //And more
  }
```

I initially had this mapped in `OnModelCreating` as:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Clients.Client>()
    .HasDiscriminator<string>("ProtocolType")
    .HasValue<Clients.SpecialClient>("special");
```

But this ended up querying the database only for protocol types `special` and `Client` - not what I wanted. I'd assumed EF would just use the base class for "all other values" but it did not. So then I tried:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Clients.Client>()
    .HasDiscriminator<string>("ProtocolType")
    .HasValue<Clients.SpecialClient>("special")
    .HasValue<Clients.Client>("type1")
    .HasValue<Clients.Client>("type2");
```

But this effectively only took the last supplied value and would only query the database for `special` and `type2`. So, I finally accepted that I'd need to introduce a redundant extra class with no extra functionality just so that I could make the mapper happy:

```
public class Type2Client : Client {}
```

And:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Clients.Client>()
    .HasDiscriminator<string>("ProtocolType")
    .HasValue<Clients.SpecialClient>("special")
    .HasValue<Clients.Client>("type1")
    .HasValue<Clients.Type2Client>("type2");
```

**Finally** - EF is happy, all is good, I can move on with my life. However, the next challenge is, clients can *change protocols*.

So, I load a client. I change its protocol type. I save it:

```
      _context.Update(client);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And EF generates this SQL:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [Clients].[Clients] SET [ClientLogoUrl] = @p0, [ClientName] = @p1
WHERE [ClientId] = @p2;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Harumph. No `SET` for the `ProtocolType` column. Is there some cunning way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change default "after save" behavior of discriminator column. By default, discriminator column has `AfterSaveBehavior` set to `Throw`. That means that if explicit value is set, or changed - exception is thrown when trying to save changes. That also means `Update` will not mark such property as modified, because that will lead to exception during `SaveChanges` anyway.

So in your case change save behavior to `Save` for discriminator column (do that after you made this column discriminator of course):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
   .Property(c => c.ProtocolType).Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Save;
```

And it should work as you expect.